# Unique Suspend Issue with Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, ati, suspend

I have a little bit of a unique issue with suspend. My Laptop suspends and resumes properly, but the built-in laptop screen does not turn back on when resuming for some strange reason. I have to do a hard reset to make the laptop screen wake back up. This problem for me is longstanding, and started with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (I now run Ubuntu 13.10) and never got fixed since (I'm thinking it is a bug that never got fixed all this time). It is an issue I believe with the graphics drivers (Stock X.org Drivers shipped with Ubuntu).

Here is another strange thing, when I have a external monitor plugged in (VGA or HDMI), and resume it from suspend (assuming it was already in suspend), the laptop screen still doesn't turn on, but the external monitor, regardless of connection, turns on normally.

My graphics card is a AMD Radeon HD 6620G, that is integrated on my AMD A8-3500M APU CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I have this also as well with my old Dell that has an ATI card in it.  Unfortunately I don't know how to fix it, but I have found a solution so I don't have to hard reset all the time.  Note that this will kill all open processes in your current session:

> 1. Press Ctrl+Alt+F1
> 2. Log in with username and password (must be able to sudo)
> 3. Run "sudo killall Xorg"    or (if the previous doesn't work)     "sudo kill -9 $(ps -A | grep X | awk '{print $1}')"
> 4. The X server will be killed and should spring back to life so you can login again without having to hard reboot.

Though not ideal, certainly an improvement for me over the hard reset.